# URL rewrite example (redirect the root context to a deployed application) with wildfly 10

Tags: web-applications, jboss, wildfly, wildfly-10, undertow

Can anyone direct me here how can i redirect the root context to a deployed application , my requirement is as below:

I have deployed application on WildFly 10.0.0 Application Name is MyApp.war.Now if I access my application it should work in both the below ways .
I tried this approach by adding jboss-web.xml to my WEB-INF

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><jboss-web xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-web_10_0.xsd"
           version="10.0">
    <context-root>/</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

I am able to access to myApp using this https://someip/myApp/ ,but I want myApp access should work in both the scenario , can you please direct me like if any user logs in using https://someip it should redirect to above mentioned url .
If anyone can share the sample example with wildfly 10 that will be very helpful.

Comment: You could just create a war called ROOT.war that just has index.jsp that contain a redirect to /myApp

Comment: sorry I didn't understand this , we are using html5 and jersey as servlet container and we don't have any jsps in our application . Can you please briefly explain  this "create a war called ROOT.war" means what ? I have already myApp.war with me which I have deployed in wildfly application server.

Comment: Create a new war, call it ROOT.war and have a single page. If you are not familiar with jsp you could have index.html with JavaScript redirect to /myApp if you want to redirect / to /myApp

Comment: Hi Will , I tried this and it worked for me , I have added in index.html this code <META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0; URL=/myApp/"/> , but there is so much blinking while loading the url . Can you suggest me something like `<rewrite name="sampleAppredirect" pattern="^/$|^$" substitution="/myApp" flags="L">
 <condition name="condition-0" test="%{SERVER_PORT}" pattern="='"$1"'" flags=","/>"
</rewrite> ` because same I did with jboss 7 it worked for me without blinking but in wildlfy 10 which tag should i use in standalone.xml ?

Comment: Hi Will, our application is already deployed in client machine now creating one more war called 'ROOT.war' for only url redirection is not feasible for my requirement. If you can please suggest me something like configuration label changes in standalone.xml which I have mentioned above using rewrite tag which i was able to do in jboos 7 but is there any alternate similar to that in wildfly ?  that will be very helpful for us .

Comment: I have not used any url rewriting sorry in any version so am not familiar with it. Version 10 uses Undertow, so it might be best to use that when searching for help

Comment: Thanks Will , I have used [link](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/242967) and got some info . You are right wildfly 10 uses Undertow and we can configure custom handlers too there . I followed above link and got some idea .